# Quel(s) livre(s) me faut-il si j'ai l'intention d'améliorer mon français (afin de me rapprocher d'un registre plus soutenu)?

Tags: ressources, registre

Je ne sais pas ce qui m'arrive... Lorsque j'écris en français, je sens que je ne sais qu'employer le registre familier. Lorsque je vais sur amazon.fr pour chercher des livres pour améliorer mon français, les commentaires que je vois m'apparaissent toujours poétiques, et remplis d'une délicatesse dont je ne sais pas me servir ! Ça m'arrive aussi dans les forums de français... Je parle également le français du Québec, mais même à l'écrit, j'ai l'impression qu'ils conversent en une autre langue... C'en est trop. Moi aussi, je veux apprendre à parler de même !

Que faire pour toujours parler de façon « soutenue » ? Est-ce que c'est quelque chose d'instinctif chez les Français que de s'adapter à un tel registre ? Chaque fois que je m'y prends je ne sais pas trop ce que je fais et ça parait artificiel... et forcé.

J'ai déjà commandé *Le bon usage*, quels autres livres/ressources devrais-je me procurer ? Pensez-vous que si jamais je maîtrisais *Le bon usage*, je me débarrasserai de ce problème ? Sinon, quels genres de livres me faudrait-il ? Vocabulaire ? Grammaire ? Exercices sur le style ? De quoi pensez-vous que j'aurais plutôt besoin ? (À partir de mon niveau de français actuel).

Comment: Nul besoin de parler un français soutenu... les occasions de s'en servir sont très rares, et l'emploi d'un registre soutenu dans la vie courante ferait plutôt sourire. Certes il est bien de comprendre toutes sortes de registres, dont la langue soutenue, mais reconnaissance et utilisation sont deux choses différentes. Peut-être confonds-tu « soutenu » et « correct » ? Pour améliorer son français, lire, beaucoup et parler /écrire en interaction avec des francophones. *Le bon usage* est un excellent ouvrage de référence mais vouloir le maîtriser me semble plutôt utopique.

Comment: Pour travailler la grammaire je recommande [ce site](http://www.bonjourdefrance.com/).

Comment: « converser » est un terme soutenu à mon avis, qui me surprend dans le paragraphe...

Comment: Personnellement, je pense que c'est un exercice assez compliqué pour un étranger. Il est déjà assez compliqué d'utiliser les bons mots dans un registre donné, alors maitriser plusieurs registres... cela peut amener à beaucoup de maladresses... Je pense qu'il est important de reconnaitre un langage soutenu (on le voit car il diffère du langage habituel), mais le parler, c'est autre chose... Je pense que l'essentiel est de maitriser le langage courant, qui passe partout, et qui est le langage que nous utilisons sur ce site...

Comment: Tout à fait Laure... sauf que j'en suis actuellement un allophone (vivant à Québec) qui a appris cette langue depuis la maternelle en tant que ma premi.

Comment: Oops correction: Oui, je pense que je m'y suis trompé Laure... sauf que ce français correct à laquelle vous fassiez allusion ressemble une créature survenu d'une autre dimension. Je suis actuellement un allophone (vivant à Québec) qui a appris le français depuis la maternelle en tant que langue d'enseignement. Je converse déjà en français à temps plein(beaucoup plus que ma langue maternelle surtout), mais il ne s'améliore pas autant, toutefois! (Peut être que c'est dû au fait que j'ai en tellement parlé du joual québécois que je m'en suis fichu du vrai français...triste.)

Comment: Suffit de lire des bouquins, plein de bouquins, surtout des qui ne sont pas traduits d'une autre langue. Le style ça vient tout seul. En tous cas c'te question est vachement marrante, wesh gros.

Comment: Je rejoins les commentaires de Laure et Anne. Le plus important me semble être de lire des livres (plutôt des classiques, mais pas forcément, sans avoir d'a priori), ou des revues (comme le [magazine littéraire](http://www.magazine-litteraire.com/) ou [l'Histoire](http://www.lhistoire.fr/)) et écouter des émissions de radio, comme France Inter ou France Culture. Dans tous les cas, le plus important et de s'amuser et d'y prendre du plaisir !

Comment: Le site de [l'Académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/) contient aussi des conseils et des articles qui peuvent être intéressants.

Comment: Il existe une multitude de supports qui contiennent tous du contenu avec une bonne qualité de langue: télévision, radio, Internet, livres, journaux, revues/magazines, conférences, etc. Il suffit de se ressourcer, d'analyser et de comprendre comment ça fonctionne.

Comment: @Random Peut-être qu'au Québec on converse là ou les français de France parlent, un de nos habitués Québécois va nous dire ça peut-être.

Comment: Merci pour vos conseils. Je réalise que je ne fais pas assez de lectures en français et cela a probablement contribué à ma stagnation. Il faut faire plus d'efforts que de se fier aux manuels/cahiers d'exercises!

Comment: Très simple: Ecouter France Culture tous les jours. :) Je ne pense pas qu'avoir un bon niveau d'expression soit si difficile...aussi, pour les programmes en français enregistrés, on peut mettre les légendes (pour les sourds-muets). La lecture du language parlé (programmes divers, p.e. sur la science, etc.) peut contribuer à améliorer le niveau de langue....

Comment: Très honnêtement, je trouve déjà le style de cette question plutôt soutenu...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ce n'est pas obligatoirement au niveau du livre qu'il faut chercher le plus, mais plutôt au niveau d'une rencontre avec *l'auteur*, celui ou celle qui a une sensibilité qui résonne en vous.

Ensuite, il faut s'apprivoiser : *l'auteur* dont je parle ne vous apprend rien, il *témoigne* de la vie qui s'écoule dans ses veines, et formule par moment des phrases que vous auriez aimé écrire vous-même, d'autres mots attirent votre regard intérieur sur des zones que les ombres partagent avec les ténèbres...

... si c'est *votre auteur*, tout un monde va se dévoiler ; mais ne pas l'imiter, ne pas le copier, revenir sans cesse au niveau de la sensation qui a été réveillée, alors vous trouverez votre formule, celle que vous pourrez afficher au monde entier sans qu'une critique loyale trouve quelque chose à redire.

Et puis *votre auteur* va vous faire rencontrer ses propres maîtres !

C'est ainsi depuis Gutenberg, et même avant dans l'oralité : il y a ceux qui savent et qui bavardent et ceux qui ont la maîtrise, ceux-là sont les plus aptes à transmettre ce dont votre être a besoin.

Pour cela, pousser la porte d'une librairie, fureter, feuilleter, parler au libraire... et se laisser guider par son instinct !

Comment: Encore un vote négatif sans commentaire, ce qui est contraire à la charte du site, ceci pour permettre l'amélioration des réponses.

Answer (score 1):

> Que faire pour toujours parler de façon « soutenue » ?

Figurez-vous que beaucoup de gens aimeraient atteindre un tel niveau dans d'autres langues également !

Atteindre un tel niveau de perfection et de maîtrise ne se fera pas en un jour, ni en un mois ou un an. Plusieurs années seront certainement nécessaires. Pour y arriver, je pense que la meilleure façon consiste à lire et s'inspirer/s'imprégner de la culture et le français de plusieurs grands auteurs français (j'ai un faible pour Victor Hugo et Molière, pour ma part).

Avec le temps, la lecture vous sera plus facile, et vous parviendrez plus facilement à employer des termes de plus en plus spécifiques à la langue que vous utilisez ; ce sera le registre soutenu.

Comment: J'ajoute personnellement Dumas à votre liste d'auteurs!

Answer (score 1):

Si tu veux vraiment pouvoir parler ou écrire en langage soutenu je ne saurais trop te conseiller les livres de Chrétien de Troyes surtout la quête du Saint Graal. Après l'avoir lu tu auras envie de parler de la même manière. Et si tu continues à en lire d'autres (de lui ou d'autres auteurs du Moyen-Âge, ils parlaient vraiment bien en ce temps-là) ça deviendra même une habitude.
Je suis une grande lectrice et je sais que les livres ont une grande influence sur ta manière de parler, de penser et même d'être mais ça c'est autre chose. Tu veux parler poétiquement, lit de la poésie (personnellement j'aime bien Victor Hugo mais Chateaubriand, Tolkien (pas strictement de la poésie mais style qui s'approche) ou encore François Cheng sont très bien aussi).

Comment: Tolkien a écrit en anglais donc vous pensez sûrement à une traduction